# Не работает фильтрация диалогов, машинное обучение

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, синтаксис, датасет

мне нужно обучить бота на основе датасета с диалогами и я пытаюсь этот датасет почистить. Но выдает ошибку синтаксиса... Перебрала все варианты, но нет. Прошу помощи, заранее спасибо.
Мой код

```
with open ("dialogues.txt") as f :
    content = f.read()
    dialogues_str = content.split("\n\n")
    dialogues = dialogues_str.split("\n") [:2] for dialogues_str dialogues_filtered = []
    questions = set()
```

Comment: У вас что-то непонятное написано в четвёртой строке `dialogues = ...`, вы что там хотели вообще сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Не особо понятно, что вы хотите, но, я предполагаю, что-то типа такого:

```py
# Читаем файл
with open ("dialogues.txt") as f :
    content = f.read()

# Разделяем отдельные диалоги, написанные челез строку 
dialogues = content.split("\n\n")
all_dialogues = []

# Разбиваем каждый диалог на строки и убираем первые два символа (видимо, `- `)
for dialogue in dialogues:
    dialogue_strs = [line[:2] for line in dialogue.split("\n")]
    all_dialogues.append(dialogue_strs)

# Дальнейшая логика
questions = set()
```